# Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect component reload data

Tags: javascript, extjs, web, frontend

So I have a Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect component that uses an Ext.data.SimpleStore like this

```
var myData = [];

var myStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        id: 0,
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        data: myData,
        ......
    });

var boxSelect = new Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect({
        fieldLabel: 'xxx',
        width: xxx,
        mode: 'local',
        hiddenName: 'xxx',
        valueField: 'xxx',
        displayField: 'xxx',
        value: xxx,
        store: myStore
    });
```

Now the value of myData variable will be updated as the user makes AJAX calls. How do I reload the SuperBoxSelect so its list items will also be updated realtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making an Ajax call , when you get the myData values, you can just use:

myStore.loadData(myData);

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following options and check if it works

```
myStore.load({params:{......}})
```

or

```
boxSelect.bindStore(myStore)
```